# python : How to allow python to not add quotation marks while changing delimiter in the csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, delimiter, quotation-marks

I have written a script to convert delimiter in the csv file from comma to pipe symbol but while doing so it doesn't remove the extra quotation marks added by csv file.

script is as follows:-

```
import csv

filename = "sample.csv"

with open(filename,mode='rU') as fin,open('c:\\files\\sample.txt',mode='w') as fout:

        reader= csv.DictReader(fin)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fout,reader.fieldnames,delimiter='|')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(reader)
```

case 1:
Now, for example if one of the field in the csv contains "hi" hows you,good then the csv will make it as """hi" hows you,good"" and python loads it as """hi" hows you,good"" in the text file instead of "hi" hows you,good

case 2:
Whereas for the fields like hi hows, you csv makes it as "hi hows,you" and after running the script it is saved as hi hows,you in the text file which is correct.

Please could you help me to solve case 1.

example csv file when you open it in notepad:-

```
ID,IDN,DESC,TNO
A019,1,"""Pins ""  is dangerous",2
B020,1,"""ache"",headache/fever-like",3
C021,2,stomach cancer,1
D231,3,"hair,""fall""",1
```

after script result:

```
ID|IDN|DESC|TNO
A019|1|"""Pins ""  is dangerous"|2
B020|1|"""ache"",headache/fever-like"|3
C021|2|stomach cancer|1
D231|3|"hair,""fall"""|1
```

i want the result as :

```
ID|IDN|DESC|TNO
A019|1|"Pins "  is dangerous|2
B020|1|"ache",headache/fever-like|3
C021|2|stomach cancer|1
D231|3|hair,"fall"|1
```

Comment: can you post the `sample.csv` input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that works:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(fout,reader.fieldnames,delimiter='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,quotechar="")
```

- defining the quoting as "no quoting": `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`
- defining the quote char as "no quote char": `quotechar=""`

result

```
ID|IDN|DESC|TNO
A019|1|"Pins "  is dangerous|2
B020|1|"ache",headache/fever-like|3
C021|2|stomach cancer|1
D231|3|hair,"fall"|1
```

note that quoting *is* useful. So disabling it exposes you to the joy of "delimiters in the fields". It's up to you to make sure it's not going to happen.

Comment: Mind you, should you ever actually use a pipe (or newline) in your CSV data, this will make it impossible to round-trip it correctly.

Comment: Added in the answer. Actually I think the OP want to create a simple file that `cut` or `awk` can parse without issues.